# .NET XmlSerializer: Serializing when property setter has additional code

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization

I have a (much abbreviated) class like this:

```
public class Widget
{
  public List<Widget> SubWidgets { get; set; }
  public Widget ParentWidget { get; set; }

  private double _ImportantValue;
  public double ImportantValue
  {
    get { return _ImportantValue; }
    set
    {
      _ImportantValue = value;
      RecalculateSubWidgets();
    }
  }
}
```

When deserializing, I don't want to RecalculateSubWidgets. What is the best way to handle this situation? The only thing I've been able to come up with so far is to set a "global" variable that says I'm deserializing and skip the call to RecalculateSubWidgets() in that case, but that seems ultra kludgy.

Comment: You could use custom serialization by implementing ISerializable: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way could be to ignore the current property and use another one for getting the deserialized value:

```
private double _ImportantValue;

[XmlElement("ImportantValue")]
public double ImportantValueFromXml
{
    get { return _ImportantValue; }
    set
    {
        _ImportantValue = value;
    }
}

[XmlIgnore]
public double ImportantValue
{
    get { return _ImportantValue; }
    set
    {
        _ImportantValue = value;
        RecalculateSubWidgets();
    }
}
```

When you deserialize the RecalculateSubWidgets() method won't be called but your private field will still have the value. Of course you might want to change your design a bit and get rid of the function call in the setter to avoid this situation but this can be a short term solution.

Comment: That seems reasonable. Thank you!